# Manejo de collection en laravel para guardar en mysql

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collection

Estoy haciendo una consulta en una tabla de la bd, y debo guardarla en otra tabla de la bd.

y al guardarla no quiero crear campo x campo para poderla guardar.
la otra tabla tiene los mismo datos, mas 2 o 3 campos mas, se que se puede guardar una collection directamente en una tabla, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo, y en la documentacion de laravel tampoco es muy clara.

Esta es la consulta que hago, para un registro en una tabla:

```
$data  = table1::where('id', $id)->first();
```

y al guardar el registro lo estoy haciendo campo por campo, en la otra tabla, pero he visto que hay maneras de guardar collection de manera directa.

```
    $insert= new tabla2;
    $insert->numero = $data->NUMERO;
    $insert->envio = $data->ENVIO;
    $insert->envio2 = $data->ENVIO2;
    $insert->envio3 = $data->ENVIO3;
    $insert->envio4 = $data->ENVIO4;
    $insert->envio5 = $data->ENVIO5;
    $insert->fechaserver  = now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $insert->periodo = 1;
    $insert-save();
```

Hay alguna manera de los campos de la tabla1 guardarlos en la tabla2, de manera de collection?
para el ejemplo usé, algunos campos, pero en la realidad son muchisimos.

quisiera poder hacer algo asi, se podria?

```
$data = new tabla2($data);
$data->fechaserver  = now()->format('Y-m-d');
$data->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haberte entendido, quieres guardar los mismos campos de la tabla 1 en la tabla 2?
No se si te sirva, pero yo lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
$data  = table1::where('id', $id)->first();

//Convierte colection a array para guardar copia.
$arr = $data->attributesToArray();

// Quita el atributo id del arreglo a copiar
$filterOutKeys = array( 'id' );
$filteredArr = array_diff_key( $arr, array_flip( $filterOutKeys ) );
$data2= table2::create($filteredArr);
// Si tienes campos extra añadir aquí
// $data2->otroCampo = $valor;
//
$data2->save();
```

Saludos.